# join non-sequential data using keys

Tags: python, pandas

My two data sets do not have matching dates. I'm struggling to find a way that will use the date of one data set as a key to locate and match the data on the other data set.
Both data sets use dated information. Id like to merge them since they don't have overlapping column names.

I have tried

```py
merge=pd.merge(df1,df2, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

This was explained to me as using a key to match data, however it did not.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was the date needed to be in datetime format. Then the above code worked as expected.

First, put the date into datetime format by;

```py
File1_datetime = pd.read_csv(file_path,
                             parse_dates = ['date'],
                             index_col = ['date'])
```

Then

```py
merge=pd.merge(File1_datetime,File2_datetime, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```